# change the label of the radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, tkinter-menu

I'm creating a menu in Tkinter. After my menu has been created I'd like to be able to change the label of the radiobutton. Something similar to the **.configure** method. How do I go about this?

I want to be able to change the radiobuttons text from "Hello" to "Hello!".

Snippet:

```
    self.B3Me = Tkinter.Menu(self, tearoff=0,
                                activebackground='grey15',
                                activeforeground='grey95')
    self.B3MeVar = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.B3Me.add_radiobutton(label='Hello', variable=self.B3MeVar,
                                 command=self.B3_menu_beh)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the label use the `entryconfig` method. You give this method an index which can be the integer position of the item, or the label itself. For example:

```
self.B3Me.entryconfig("Hello", label="Goodbye!")
```